# Multiple logins accessing specific results without using groups in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app set up using standard Django user auth. In which users can log in, add their players (Player model - Foreign Key to User model), and add results for their players (Results model - Foreign Key to Player model).

I would like to also have the players (each entry in Player model) that the user creates be able to log in, but only be able to edit/add their own results. Just to be clear, the user and player would see the same results for that player, and each be able to add and edit them.

I don't believe this can be done with groups as the group would have to be user specific. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of: You can use a custom authentication backend. Allow someone to enter a playername and password (or whatever you use for authorisation). Log in the user associated with that player (in order to be able to keep using Django's authentication system), but store which player was selected.

When editing player results, instead of checking only whether the player belongs to the correct user, also check whether it is in fact the player logged in as (if any).